# Having Issues in Animating and moivng Pacman in java

Tags: java, animation, jquery-animate, keylistener, pacman

For animating I am using a strip of pacman images (mouth open , half closed , full closed) different for each direction, and drawing them by:

```
frame = 0;

public  void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);    
    g.drawImage(PacRIGHT.getSubimage(frame, 0, 28, 28), x, y, null);
}
```

to animate the pacman , frame is to be * by 30 to move 30 pixels right and >= 60 to complete 1 animation cycle , that will be like:

```
frame = 0*30 ;
frame = 1*30 ;
frame = 2*30 ;
```

and here we have 4 different image strip to draw for every direction , first problem I'm facing to figure out way to do it and also i m not able to move it , here is the code

---

**UPDATE :** USED swing timer this time CODE is been updated , now i have moving Pacman and animated mouth of right direction [image] problem is now i'm getting multiple errors .

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Runtest extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(4, this);
    int x, y, velocx, velocy = 0;
    int keyCode;
    int frame = 0;

    BufferedImage PacUP;
    BufferedImage PacDOWN;
    BufferedImage PacLEFT;
    BufferedImage PacRIGHT;

    public Runtest() throws IOException {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        PacRIGHT = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\javapacman\\newright.png"));

    }

    public int frame() {

        frame++;
        if (frame > 3)
            frame = 0;

        return frame;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(PacRIGHT.getSubimage(frame() * 30, 0, 28, 28), x, y, null);

        // Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g ;
        // g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,40,40));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        repaint();
        x += velocx;
        y += velocy;
    }

    public void up() {
        velocy = -1;
        velocx = 0;

    }

    public void down() {
        velocy = 1;
        velocx = 0;

    }

    public void left() {
        velocx = -1;
        velocy = 0;

    }

    public void right() {
        velocx = 1;
        velocy = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        keyCode = ke.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();

        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }

    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
public class PacMan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
         Runtest test = new Runtest();
         frame.setSize(400, 400);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.add(test);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Errors i'm getting

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:      Not supported yet.
at pactest.Runtest.keyReleased(Runtest.java:128)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6466)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2828)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: To start with I would separate movement and animation - use 1 image to begin with and just get the movement working.  After that then approach the image switching problem.

Comment: my first focus was also moving the image first and then figure out the way to draw , but stuck on movement have tried different approaches but failed ,

Comment: @AMATURE you need something to move the packman, you currently have something in `actionPerformed` but I dont know how that ever gets called. I awnsered a question a while back about game loops http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364487/java-rendering-loop-and-logic-loop/16364639#16364639 maybe you can take that code and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if I were you I would separate movement and animation.  Get the movement working first with one set image.

**Movement:**
On key events you're changing the velocity parameters, this seems good.  It seems that you are using the `x` and `y` variables in `MyPanel` as position variables.  *You should set these to an initial value somewhere - either in the constructor or in the instance variable declaration.*

You have the right idea about modifying the `x` and `y` variables with the velocity variables, but you're doing that in the `actionPerformed` method.  That isn't what you want.  You need to update the position variables based off of time, not user input.  You should look into game loops as @ug_ mentioned.  A game loop basically is a loop that runs in your game that continuously: checks for input, updates game information, and renders the changes.  You should update the position variable in a game loop.  Make sure to call `repaint` after modifying the position variables so that the screen reflects the changes.

Once you are updating the position variable correctly, then you need to use those `x` and `y` variables as position parameters in your `paintComponent` method when calling `g.drawImage`.  That way the position of the image is drawn where you're tracking `x` and `y`.

**Animation:**
Once you have the movement working then you should figure out the image switching.  A suggestion for this would to have an instance variable of `curImage` that your `g.drawImage` call uses.  You would then use your "game loop" to handle cycling through your 3 images in order to choose which image to set as `curImage`.  This would be based off of time so for example every 1/2 second you could change the image to the next one in the collection.  When you get to the end of the collection you would move in reverse through the collection.  So the order would be: `open, half, close, half, open, half, etc..`.  You could also do this easily with an index counter that was set to 0 initially, is incremented every time an image is chosen, and then decremented when the final image in the collection  was reached, repeat process when back at start.

Also, you mentioned that you have different sets of images for each direction.  In the game loop you could check the velocity parameters to determine which direction was being traveled.  That information would tell you which image collection to pull the images from.  You could then use the index counter you have to get the right image out of that collection.

Comment: can i use a javax.swing.Timer that calls the method that update  game state every xx milliseconds

Comment: @AMATURE There are multiple ways you could do it, so I'm sure you could get it to work that way

Comment: @AMATURE The problem you are having now is a completely different issue.  Your original question/problem was answered.  You shouldn't edit your original question - you should create a new question.  If my answer solved your original problem then please accept it so the question doesn't remain open.

Comment: having issues becoz of the moving the image when ever i press keys, so is that not relevant ?

Comment: Your original question was about why your movement wasn't working with your original code and how to do the animation - now your question is about a specific error you receive.  Anyways if you're implementing KeyListener you need to override `keyPressed`, `keyReleased`, and `keyTyped` methods.  Also, not sure why you still have that `actionPerformed` method.  You can probably stop implementing `ActionListener`.